# Keep divs aligned and paragraph

Tags: html, css, resize

I have been helped once and I would like some more help with keeping elements in same place or resize but adjust to window viewport size so it still looks the same on a tablet, mobile or different monitor size.

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="file://C:/Users/cody/Desktop/offline_website/CSS/care.css">

</head> 










<body>



  <div class = "mainthing">





           <div class = "pilli">

             <img class="pillipic" src="file://C:/Users/cody/Desktop/offline_website/Images/pilli.jpg">

<h1> Suja Pilli MD. </h1>


            <pre>

Education:     
2008-2011                     
           Valley Baptist Family Practice
           Residency Program
           Harlingen, TX
           Family Practice

1993-1999
          Universitatea Ovidius
          Consatanta, Romania
          Doctor of Medicine, September 1999

Medical Licensure and Certification:
         Texas Medical Board

            </pre>



</div>













            <div class="shaun">
              <img class="shaunpic" src="file://C:/Users/cody/Desktop/offline_website/Images/shaun.jpg">



<h1> Shaun Adams FNP. </h1>
   <pre>
Education:     
2012-2014 

         Univesrity Texas Medical Branch
         Galveston, TX
         Masters of Science in Nursing

2010-2011

         Univesrity of Texas Brownsville
         Brownsville, TX
         Bachelors of Science in Nursing.

2005-2007

        University of Texas Brownsville
        Brownsville, TX
        Associates Degree in Nursing

Medical Licensures and Certification:

        Texas Medical Board of Nursing Family
        Nurse Practioner Certified License
        Nurge Register Nurse License
        BLS, ACLS, TNCC, ENPC
</pre>



            </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* .body
{
    margin-top: 20vh;
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-bottom: 20vh;
    margin-right: 20vw;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;

}
 */

.mainthing {
    margin-top: 20vh;
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-bottom: 20vh;
    margin-right: 20vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* position: absolute; */ 
}
.pilli {
    /* ADDED THIS */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;


}
.pillipic {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;

}
.shaun {
    /* ADDED THIS */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;


}
.shaunpic {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;


}


pre
 {  
   text-align:  left;
   font-family: "courier new", courier, monospace;
   font-size: 11px;
   float: left;


}
```

So the main questions I have is the text appears in the correct place next to image but when I add another line it shifts to the left when I want it to stay vertical next to the picture.

The other problem I am having is on resize all the elements shift.

I tried making a wrapper with the body tag but I don't really have an understanding of how wrappers work based on pixel width.  I also tried making the body with an relative position with all of its child divs absolute positions but, that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

## [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/n6qyrvyw/6/)

What you're looking for is a [fluid layout](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/).

The main thing getting in the way of this is using `<pre>` tags for regular formatting that you intend to be viewed with different browser sizes.

I put the education years inside of a `div` with the CSS class of `.title` corresponding to this CSS:

```
.title {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Then I put the education content inside of a `div` with the CSS class of `.content` which gives is a margin of 20% to keep everything indented.

`.content` CSS:

```
.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  /* Optional .content styles */
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}
```

### Full CSS

```
.mainthing {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
  margin-right: 20vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.pilli {
  /* ADDED THIS */
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.pillipic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.shaun {
  /* ADDED THIS */
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.shaunpic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

pre {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "courier new", courier, monospace;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: left;
}


/* New Stuff */

body {
  font-size: 11px;
}

h2 {
  /* Options h2 styles */
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}

.title {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
  text-align: left;
  /* Optional .content styles */
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}
```

### Full HTML

```
<div class="mainthing">
  <div class="pilli">
    <img class="pillipic" src="http://i.imgur.com/alhBkw5.png">
    <h1> Suja Pilli MD. </h1>
    <h2>Education:</h2>
    <div class="title">
      2008-2011
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Valley Baptist Family Practice Residency Program Harlingen, TX Family Practice
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      1993-1999
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Universitatea Ovidius Consatanta, Romania Doctor of Medicine, September 1999
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Medical Licensure and Certification:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Texas Medical Board
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="shaun">
    <img class="shaunpic" src="http://i.imgur.com/alhBkw5.png">
    <h1> Shaun Adams FNP. </h1>
    <h2>
      Education:
    </h2>
    <div class="title">
      2012-2014
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Univesrity Texas Medical Branch Galveston, TX Masters of Science in Nursing
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      2010-2011
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Univesrity of Texas Brownsville Brownsville, TX Bachelors of Science in Nursing.
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      2005-2007
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      University of Texas Brownsville Brownsville, TX Associates Degree in Nursing Medical Licensures and Certification: Texas Medical Board of Nursing Family Nurse Practioner Certified License Nurge Register Nurse License BLS, ACLS, TNCC, ENPC
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the snippet, I simplified your CSS and converted it to FLEXBOX. If that is not what you want, cool. Your HTML is unchanged but now fully responsive.

On smaller screens (max 720px see @media query) the C.V.'s are shown below eachother.

I added some empty CSS rules and demo code showing what you could do with the HTML code you already have.

See the comments in the snippet for an explanation.

(The final @media should read `.card { width: calc(50% - 8px) }` for your requirement. Now only `35%` to show flexbox behaviour)

Have fun testing and fiddling...

```css
/* * { outline: 1px dashed red } /* for debugging remove beginning slash */

#main { /* main card holding container */
    display: flex;              /* make it a flex container */
    flex-flow: row wrap;        /* main contents are 2 columns inside a row */
    justify-content: center;    /* position cards with margins on either side */
    max-width: 90%;             /* only 90% of body width */ 
    margin: 10% auto;           /* 5% top margin, main centered in body */
}
.card { /* main definition of a c.v. card */
    display: flex;              /* make it a flex container */
    flex-flow: column nowrap;   /* card contents are rows inside a column */
    align-items: center;        /* center card contents */ 
    width: calc(100% - 8px);    /* full width of main, mobile first */
    margin: 4px;                /* some space outside cards */
    padding: 4px;               /* some inside space */
    background-color: #fafafa;  /* off white demo color */
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px rgba(42, 47, 57, 0.2);
}
.card *   { /* add your general rules for anything inside card    */ }
.card > * { /* add your general rules for direct children of card */ }
.card h1  { /* exceptions for a H1 */ }
.card img { /* exceptions for an IMG */
              max-width: 33%;   /* some max/min image width */
              min-width: 165px;
}
.card pre { /* exceptions for a PRE */
              padding: 4px;
              font-size: 11px;
              font-family: "courier new", courier, monospace;
}
@media all and (min-width: 721px) {
    .card { width: calc(35% - 8px) }    /* moves cards side by side on larger screens */
}
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500">
            <!-- img src="file://C:/Users/cody/Desktop/offline_website/Images/pilli.jpg" -->
            <h1>Suja Pilli MD.</h1>
<pre>

Education:     
2008-2011                     
           Valley Baptist Family Practice
           Residency Program
           Harlingen, TX
           Family Practice

1993-1999
          Universitatea Ovidius
          Consatanta, Romania
          Doctor of Medicine, September 1999

Medical Licensure and Certification:
         Texas Medical Board

            </pre>
        </div>
 
       <div class="card">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500">
            <!-- img src="file://C:/Users/cody/Desktop/offline_website/Images/shaun.jpg" -->
            <h1>Shaun Adams FNP.</h1>
            <pre>
Education:     
2012-2014 

         Univesrity Texas Medical Branch
         Galveston, TX
         Masters of Science in Nursing

2010-2011

         Univesrity of Texas Brownsville
         Brownsville, TX
         Bachelors of Science in Nursing.

2005-2007

        University of Texas Brownsville
        Brownsville, TX
        Associates Degree in Nursing

Medical Licensures and Certification:

        Texas Medical Board of Nursing Family
        Nurse Practioner Certified License
        Nurge Register Nurse License
        BLS, ACLS, TNCC, ENPC
</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
```